# How to print the empty data present in a table from its HTML code?

Tags: python, html-parsing

I am using the HTMLParser module present in python to print the data in a table by parsing the HTML page through the HTMLParser. I am unable to print the empty field in the table.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
class MyParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, data ):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.feed(data)
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print "result -->", data

m = MyParser("""<p>105</p><p></p>""")
```

result --> 105

I am able to print the data between the first tag `<p>105</p>`. I want to print the empty data present between the second tag `<p></p>`. How do I do it?

```
HTMLPAGE  = """<p>105</p></td><td style="width:50px; word-wrap: break-word;"><p style="width: 8em; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; margin: 0pt;"></p></td><td style="width:50px; word-wrap: break-word;">"""
```

**I want print the data as the empty string(""). Any help?..**

Comment: What do you expect to print when there is nothing to print?

Comment: More importantly, what do you _want_ to print when there's nothing to print?

Comment: handle_data as the name suggest that it is function for handling data, when there is no data then this is not called. have you ever used this `if data: do_something` what is if check is here for?? it is to check if we have data or not :)

Comment: I've merged your unregistered accounts, you should now be able to manage your questions / comments without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really need this, try using `handle_endtag`:

```
class MyParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, data ):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.data = ""
        self.feed(data)
    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def handle_endtag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "result -->", self.data
        self.data = ""

m = MyParser("""<p>105</p><p></p>""")
```

This way every time tag ends, you will print the data that was inside. This will, however, treat `<p><p></p></p>` as two times "empty data" - before every tag ending. If this is close to (but not exactly) what you need, try spending some time on using also `handle_starttag`, so your code can behave the way you want it to.