# Python HTMLParser - extract "empty" data between two tags

Tags: python, html

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    b1 = False

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag =="ul":
            self.b1 = True

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.b1:
            print(data)
            self.b1 = False

parser = MyHTMLParser()

parser.feed('<ul class="player-metadata floatleft"></ul><p>Gros caca</p><p>Zuul</p>')
```

I want to extract the data between `<ul class="player-metadata floatleft">` and `</ul>` which is empty. However, even though I flagged the `<ul>` tag, the `handle_data` function prints the first data found after `<ul class="player-metadata floatleft"></ul>`:

"Gros caca"

I would like to print "nothing" and that `len(data)` returns `0`.

Could you please help me? I am also not allowed to use BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty much a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007858/how-to-print-the-empty-data-present-in-a-table-from-its-html-code).

The idea is to hold on to the start tag and the enclosed data whenever a tag is processed, then using these to do things when the parser handles the end tag, like so:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    _data = ''
    _starttag = ''

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self._starttag = tag

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if self._starttag == 'ul' and self._data == '':
            print('nothing')
        elif (...):
            (...)
        else:
            print(self._data)
```

This will handle empty strings and return `0` for `len(self._data)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wish I could upvote your answer!

Also I believe you meant print(self._data) for the last line.

Comment: Yeah, but you get the gist. ;) Glad I could help.

Comment: I believe you can accept the answer even with a low score, which will remove the [tag:unanswered] tag from the question.